# Python: When using place what is the correct way to move widgets?

Tags: python, widget

Up until now to move widgets I have been issuing another .place on it.  I wonder if that is creating another instance of the widget in memory or not?

If it is creating another copy in memory, what is the correct way to move a widget when using place?  Do I need to keep destroying the widget and placing it perhaps over and over?

Answer (score 0):

Now that I think about it, as long as I do a .place_forget() prior to any .place that should take care of any extra instances in memory.  Can anyone confirm?